# How to push commits pushed to tag to another branch

Tags: git, jenkins, npm

I am creating the tag through

```
npm version 1.0.0
```

After having the committed tag, npm version does that for me, it also updates the package.json, I do

```
git push origin 1.0.0
```

Now, I want to get the same changes (basically the package.json) to my branch. I thought of naively doing

```
git push origin master
```

but this complains of

> error: src refspec test does not match any.

I then came across these commands

```
git commit -a --amend --no-edit
git branch temp-branch
git checkout master
git merge temp-branch
git push origin master
```

and they seem to work. But I do not understand it.

These commands are being executed in Jenkins build

Comment: Does test  branch exists in remote ?

Comment: within the jenkins runtime `VERSION_BRANCH` is an *environment variable* and `${VERSION_BRANCH}` is the way to access it.  I doubt that it exists in your local machine...

Comment: sorry for unclearity. I have edited the post

Comment: I’m confused. `npm version` doesn’t create a tag.